# Getting "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE" error while trying to insert values in to Mssql database through Typeorm

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

I am using Nestjs for a project, I am trying to insert values into Mssql database through Typeorm, I am getting the following error when I try to insert

**TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received type number (0)**

Below is the log while trying to insert

```
query: BEGIN TRANSACTION
query: DECLARE @OutputTable TABLE ("id" int);

INSERT INTO "test"("name", "code", "phone") OUTPUT INSERTED."id" INTO @OutputTable VALUES (@0, @1, @2);

SELECT * FROM @OutputTable -- PARAMETERS: [{"value":"aa","type":"nvarchar","params":[]}, 
{"value":"aa","type":"nvarchar","params":[]},{"value":"323","type":"nvarchar","params":[]}]
```

Below is the code for inserting the data.

```
async create(createTestDto: CreateTestDto): Promise<TestEntity> {
const test = new TestEntity();
test.name = 'aa';
test.code = 'aa';
test.phone = '323';
await this.testRepository.save(test);
return test;
}
```

Test Entity

```
import {
Entity,
Column,
PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
CreateDateColumn,
UpdateDateColumn,
ObjectID,
Index,
PrimaryColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

@Entity({ name: 'test' })
export class TestEntity {
constructor(data?: Partial<TestEntity>) {
Object.assign(this, data);
}

@ApiProperty({ type: 'string' })
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
name: string;

@Column()
code: string;

@Column()
phone: string;

}
```

Error Log

```
events.js:292
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type 
string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received type number (0)
at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:728:11)
at RpcRequestPayload.generateParameterData (F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\lib\rpcrequest-payload.js:77:71)
at generateParameterData.next (<anonymous>)
at RpcRequestPayload.generateData (F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\lib\rpcrequest-payload.js:68:19) at generateData.next (<anonymous>)
at F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable- 
stream\lib\internal\streams\from.js:43:35    
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at asyncGeneratorStep (F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\from.js:3:103)
at _next (F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable- stream\lib\internal\streams\from.js:5:194)
at F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\from.js:5:364    
Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
at emitErrorNT (F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable- stream\lib\internal\streams\destroy.js:87:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (F:\Project\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\destroy.js:57:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Do you have the error log?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan, I have updated my question with the error log. Please check

Comment: Could you also add your entity class for `TestEntity`?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan, I have added the TestEntity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the node_modules folder and force clear the NPM cache and finally reinstalling the node dependencies.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

referred below link to solve

https://peterthaleikis.com/posts/how-to-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your `create` method like below:

```js
async create(createTestDto: CreateTestDto): Promise<TestEntity> {
  const test = new TestEntity();
  test.name = 'aa';
  test.code = 'aa';
  test.phone = '323';
  return this.testRepository.save(test);
}
```

Change the annotation in your `TestEntity` class:

```js
@ApiProperty({ type: 'number' })
```

Comment: Did you build the app again? Like `npm run build`

Comment: Based on your log, it seems like the insert operation went okay. Could you check the database and verify that the data you inserted are inside it?

Comment: I will get the results when I try to get data, I am getting this error when I try to insert data and also get data by Id. Basically when we add parameters.

Comment: What is your API call looks like?

Comment: I am sending it as json
{
    "name": "CD",
    "code": "CD",
    "phone": "2323"
}

Comment: I think we can continue the discussion in the chat?